# TabView with Page style causes strange Navigation

Tags: swiftui

I have a TabView with three tabs using `.page` style:

```swift
enum Tab {
  case accounts, lootbox
}

struct AppView: View {
    @State private var currentTab:Tab = .lootbox
    
    var body: some View {
            TabView(selection: $currentTab){
                AccountView()
                    .tabItem {
                        Label("Accounts", systemImage: "person.crop.circle")
                    }
                    .tag(Tab.accounts)
                Lootbox()
                    .tabItem {
                        Label("Lootbox", systemImage: "shippingbox")
                    }
                    .tag(Tab.lootbox)
            }
            .tabViewStyle(.page)
    }
}
```

And the Lootbox page as follows:

```swift
struct Lootbox: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            Text("SomeText")
                .navigationTitle("Lootbox")
        }
    }
}
```

The app opens in a broken navigation where a back button is displayed:

After swiping left or right to the other tab the error is gone. Is this a bug or can I not mix a NavigationView with a TabView as I did.
[image]

Update:

Before swipe left and right:

[image]

After (how it should be):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

add `.navigationViewStyle(.stack)` to your `Lootbox` `NavigationView`, works for me.

EDIT-1:

This is the test code I used, created using macos 12.2, Xcode 13.2,
targets ios 15.2 and macCatalyst 12.1.

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct TestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        AppView()
    }
}

enum Tab {
  case accounts, lootbox
}

struct AppView: View {
    @State private var currentTab:Tab = .lootbox
    
    var body: some View {
            TabView(selection: $currentTab){
                AccountView()
                    .tabItem {
                        Label("Accounts", systemImage: "person.crop.circle")
                    }
                    .tag(Tab.accounts)
                Lootbox()
                    .tabItem {
                        Label("Lootbox", systemImage: "shippingbox")
                    }
                    .tag(Tab.lootbox)
            }
            .tabViewStyle(.page)
    }
}

struct AccountView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("AccountView")
    }
}

// other test
struct AccountView2: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            Text("AccountView")
         .navigationTitle("Accounts")
        }.navigationViewStyle(.stack)  // <-- here
    }
}

struct Lootbox: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            Text("Lootbox")
         .navigationTitle("Lootbox")
        }.navigationViewStyle(.stack)  // <-- here
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work for me. What iOS are you running and which device? For me its iOS 15.2 and the iPhone 13.

Comment: I'm using macos 12.2, Xcode 13.2, 
targets ios 15 and macCatalyst 12. Tested on real devices (iPhone ios15.3), not Preview. 
It could be very different on older systems.

Comment: updated my answer with the code I used in my tests.

Comment: My problem was that I put the style modifier also inside the NavigationView instead. However now if I have a `VStack` inside the `NavigationView`, the View appears behind the navigation view title... Again I have to swipe right and left to go away. I added the image to the question.

Comment: does the code in my answer work for you? Test the code on real devices, not Preview.

Comment: Yes and no. It solves the problem of the navigation problem but the View inside the navigation stack is broken. I have rewritten the question here as it seems a different problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70671785/broken-navigationview-layout-swiftui-on-tabview-and-tabviewstyle-set-to-page