# Broken NavigationView Layout SwiftUI on TabView and TabViewStyle set to .page

Tags: swiftui

I have the following code

```
enum Tab {
  case accounts, lootbox
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var currentTab:Tab = .lootbox
    
    var body: some View {
            TabView(selection: $currentTab){
                AccountView()
                    .tabItem {
                        Label("Accounts", systemImage: "person.crop.circle")
                    }
                    .tag(Tab.accounts)
                Lootbox()
                    .tabItem {
                        Label("Lootbox", systemImage: "shippingbox")
                    }
                    .tag(Tab.lootbox)
            }
            .tabViewStyle(.page)
    }
}

struct AccountView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            VStack{
                Text("AccountView")
                Spacer()
            .navigationTitle("Lootbox")
           }
        }
       .navigationViewStyle(.stack)
    }
}

struct Lootbox: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            VStack{
                Text("Lootbox")
                Spacer()
            }
         .navigationTitle("Lootbox")
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(.stack)
    }
}
```

The `VStack`hides behind the navigation view title. After swiping right and left, it is as expected. Why is that? Or is this a bug of SwiftUI?

Before swipe left and right:

[image]

After (how it should be):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that it's not an advised use case as swipe gesture to go back in navigation stack will conflict with swipe to change tabs.

If you use regular tabs (with TabBar), not .page style, it works as expected.